# how to handle "ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA" in python database connectivity

Tags: python, database, oracle

I have written the below code as a practice on PDBC

```
import cx_Oracle
con=cx_Oracle.connect('scott/tiger@localhost')
if con:
    print("success..")
    con.close()
else:
    print("error")
```

and I got below error

```
DatabaseError: ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA
```

please help me to sort it out

Answer (score 3):

`con` should be modified so that it contains some more info: `port` and `service name`

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect('scott/tiger@localhost:1521/service_name')
                                               ----
                                               port
```

Port *usually* is `1521`; service name depends on what you chose. If it is an Oracle XE (Express edition), might be `xe`. Ask your DBA.

Comment: The cx_Oracle documentation on connection string formats is https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connection-strings

Comment: Which means that service name you used isn't valid. Where did you get it from?